# Regex problems - finding exact variable

Tags: java, regex

i'm looking to change the following code:

```
    x = 0;
            dx = (val - (x * x)) / (2.0 * x);
            x = x + dx;
            diff = val - (x * x);
            x = x;
return (x);
```

into:

```
VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = 0;
                dx = (val - (VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x * VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x)) / (2.0 * VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x);
                VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x + dx;
                diff = val - (VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x * VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x);
                VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x;
    return (VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x);
```

currently i'm using:

```
strLine.matches("^.*(?<![a-zA-Z])" +variableN[1] + "(?![a-zA-Z]).*$")
```

but this returns the following:

```
    VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = 0;
            dVARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = (val - (VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x * VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x)) / (2.0 * VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x);
            VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x + dVARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x;
            diff = val - (VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x * VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x);
            VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x = VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x;
return (VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_x);
```

how can i tweak this regex to to not catch instances that are not specifically the variable i am looking for? This catches instances where the variable is contained within another word...

any help would be greatly appreciated..

regex noob..

**EDIT:**
here is the code that replaces as well..

```
if (strLine.matches("^.*(?<![a-zA-Z])" + variableN[1] + "(?![a-zA-Z]).*$"))
{
    strLine = strLine.replace(variableN[1], VARIABLES + variableN[1]);
}
```

Comment: arggggg, my eyes!!! my eyes!!!

Comment: :) i feel the same way... dx is being changed alone with other 'x' variables..

Comment: Consider using shorter variable names that conform to Java standards. There's no need to make things harder for yourself and more importantly, for us.

Comment: if i could highlight the changes i would, but i really can't make it easier... if you look at the first bit of code you will see the 'dx' value...

Comment: The code that you've posted actually works fine: it correctly identifies only those lines that actually refer to the variable `x`. The problem is in the code that performs the replacement *within* those lines. Since you haven't posted that code, we can't help you fix it!

Comment: @ruakh sure, i've posted how i replace it as well....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\b
```

This is a great time to use "word boundaries"!

```
strLine.split("\\b" +variableN[1] + "\\b");
```

will return an array of line pieces broken up by just your variable name exactly.  "\b" matches the edge of a word.

You can then print it out a piece at a time using your new variable name to glue it together.  Or better yet:

```
strLine.replaceAll("\\b" +variableN[1] + "\\b", "VARIABLE_TO_MONITOR_" + variableN[1]);
```

Will do all the replacement for you!